# REST API: Design routes based on roles

Tags: rest, api, restful-architecture

I'm currently creating a CRUD for Users on my system, there are two kinds of users (Parent users and child users).
A parent user can get/update/delete the permissions of his childs so i was thinking to create the following endpoints on my API:

GET /parents/{parentId}/childs/{childId}/permissions 
PUT /parents/{parentId}/childs/{childId}/permissions 
DELETE /parents/{parentId}/childs/{childId}/permissions/{permissionId}

But there is a third type of user (Admin) that can get/update/remove the permissions of any user he wants, so i was thinking on creating another set of endpoints:

GET /users/{userId}/permissions 
PUT /users/{userId}/permissions 
DELETE /users/{userId}/permissions/{permissionId}

Now the problem with this approach is that i would end with a lot of endpoints that do the same, so my question is: there is a best practice for rest endpoints when there are different roles or is it fine to have multiple endpoints that perform the same action?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably organize it so that you only have the admin end points, and use a role to determine what actions are valid. For instance, if we're looking at permissions, the parent would issue /user/{userid}/permissions/{permissionId} where the userid and permission id corresponds to that of their child. If it is, the call executes and returns a 200. However, if they issue that command for someone who isn't their child, it returns an unauthorized.

For permissions, i would use a mechanism like a java web token that gets passed to the endpoint with every request.